# Turning printing out by using contains() as oppose to matches() using the same print format

Tags: java

The code below prints out "Yes" if it finds the words "hello" and "goodbye" in the String variable text in that order. My question is, is it possible to replace the matches method with the contains method in the same system.out.println format? Or, at least something similar like that?

```
System.out.println(text.matches("(?i)^.*\\bhello\\b.*\\bgoodbye\\b.*$") ? "Yes" : "No"));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about :

```
System.out.println((text.contains("hello")&&text.contains("goodbye")) ? "Yes" : "No");
```

Comment: Yes! That! Exactly. Thanks. But you can also do this: System.out.println((text.contains("hello goodbye")) ? "Yes" : "No"); By the way, what does the question mark stand for?

Comment: One more question: How come the matches method have all those weird symbols in it, but the contains print out method looks really simple?

Comment: You cannot use this method if you want the strings to appear in a particular order. Also this would also match 'somehellosome somegoodbyesome' since it doesn't check for word boundary

Comment: ...Really? Well, can you explain all the weird symbols in the matches method?

Comment: @nmelssx The `matches()` method uses a regular expression. See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html

Comment: System.out.println((Pattern.matches("hello goodbye")) ? "Yes" : "No"); So you can do something like that? @Kayaman

Comment: Also, can someone tell me what the i, and the b in my code above means?

Answer (score 0):

`String.contains` only works with String. Not with regex. It finds the given substring in the string.  It also doesn't check for word boundary. Only substring

`String.matches` would be the perfect option for what you are looking for.